# In Highcharts, how to avoid 'max' value being calculated wrong?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I struggle to get my plotbands to fill the whole width of my gauge graph, since the `max` property of the y-axis apparently being automagically calculated. How can I avoid this, or work my way around it?

For instance, when I set `max: 11000`, the result is `max: 12000`

```js
$(function() {

  // Make sure the gauges have correct height on initial load
  calculateGaugeHeight();

  // And make sure the height is re-calculated on window resize
  $(window).on('load resize', function() {
    calculateGaugeHeight();
  });

  var settings = {
    gaugeMinValue: 0,
    gaugeMaxValue: 11000,
    gaugeStartValue: 3500,
    gaugeStartAngle: -180,
    gaugeEndAngle: 180,
    gaugeUpdateInterval: 500 // ms
  };

  var options = {
    tooltip: {
      enabled: false
    },
    chart: {
      type: 'gauge',
      events: {
        load: function() {
          this.textRendered = []
        }
      }
    },

    title: false,

    pane: {
      startAngle: settings.gaugeStartAngle,
      endAngle: settings.gaugeEndAngle
    },

    plotOptions: {
      gauge: {
        dial: {
          radius: 0
        },
        pivot: {
          radius: 0
        },
        dataLabels: {
          borderWidth: 0,
          padding: 0,
          verticalAlign: 'middle',
          style: false,
          formatter: function() {
            var output = '<div class="gauge-data">';
            output += '<span class="gauge-value">' + this.y + '</span>';
            output += '</div>';

            return output;
          },
          useHTML: true
        }
      },
      pie: {
        dataLabels: false,
        animation: false,
        startAngle: settings.gaugeStartAngle,
        endAngle: settings.gaugeEndAngle,
        center: ['50%', '50%'],
        states: {
          hover: {
            enabled: false
          }
        }
      }
    },

    // the value axis
    yAxis: {
      offset: 0,
      min: settings.gaugeMinValue,
      max: settings.gaugeMaxValue,

      title: false,
      labels: false,
      minTickInterval: 0,
      tickAmount: 0,
      endOnTick: false,
      plotBands: [{
        thickness: 25,
        outerRadius: "100%",
        from: settings.gaugeMinValue,
        to: settings.gaugeStartValue,
        label: {}
      }, {
        thickness: 25,
        outerRadius: "100%",
        from: settings.gaugeStartValue,
        to: settings.gaugeMaxValue,
        label: {}
      }]
    },

    series: [{
      type: 'gauge',
      data: [settings.gaugeStartValue],
    }, {
      type: 'pie',
      innerSize: '87%',
      className: 'pizza',
      data: [{
        y: settings.gaugeStartValue,
        name: 'Data 1',
        className: 'customSeries1'
      }, {
        y: settings.gaugeMaxValue - settings.gaugeStartValue,
        name: 'Data 2',
        className: 'customSeries2'
      }]
    }],

    navigation: {
      buttonOptions: {
        enabled: false
      }
    },

    credits: false
  };

  $('#gauge1').highcharts(options, buildGraph);

  function buildGraph(chart) {
    if (!chart.renderer.forExport) {
      //setInterval(function() {
setTimeout(function() {
        var gaugePoint = chart.series[0].points[0],
          piePoint = chart.series[1],
          yAxis = chart.yAxis[0],
          newVal,
          inc = Math.round((Math.random() - 0.5) * 1500);

        newVal = gaugePoint.y + inc;
        if (newVal < settings.gaugeMinValue || newVal > settings.gaugeMaxValue) {
          newVal = gaugePoint.y - inc;
        }

        // Update number gauge value
        gaugePoint.update(newVal);

        // Update pie with current value
        piePoint.points[0].update(newVal);
        piePoint.points[1].update(settings.gaugeMaxValue - newVal);
        yAxis.update({
          plotBands: [{
            thickness: 25,
            outerRadius: "100%",
            from: settings.gaugeMinValue,
            to: newVal
          }, {
            thickness: 25,
            outerRadius: "100%",
            from: newVal,
            to: settings.gaugeMaxValue
          }]
        });
        renderText('Text 1', yAxis.plotLinesAndBands[0], 0);
        renderText('Text 2', yAxis.plotLinesAndBands[1], 1);

        console.log("Wanted max: " + settings.gaugeMaxValue + ", actual max: " + yAxis.max);

     }, settings.gaugeUpdateInterval);
    }
  }

  function renderText(textStr, plotBand, i) {
    var id = `plot-band-${i}`;
    var chart = plotBand.axis.chart;
    var path = plotBand.svgElem;
    var textRendered = chart.textRendered;
    path.attr('id', id);

    if (!textRendered[i]) {
      var text = chart.renderer.createElement('text')
        .attr({
          zIndex: 99,
          dy: 20,
          //'text-anchor': 'middle',
        }).add();

      var textPath = chart.renderer.createElement('textPath').attr({
        startOffset: '25%'
      }).attr({
        class: 'plotband-label ' + textStr
      }).add(text);

      textPath.element.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'href', '#' + id)

      var textNode = document.createTextNode(textStr)
      textPath.element.appendChild(textNode)
      textRendered[i] = true
    }
  }

  function calculateGaugeHeight() {
    var div = $('.gauge');
    div.height(div.width());
  }
});
```

```css
/**
         * @license Highcharts
         *
         * (c) 2009-2016 Torstein Honsi
         *
         * License: www.highcharts.com/license
         */

    .highcharts-container {
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      text-align: left;
      line-height: normal;
      z-index: 0;
      /* #1072 */
      -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
      font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      font-size: 12px;
    }

    .highcharts-root text {
      stroke-width: 0;
    }

    .highcharts-strong {
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    .highcharts-emphasized {
      font-style: italic;
    }

    .highcharts-background {
      fill: #ffffff;
    }

    .highcharts-plot-border,
    .highcharts-plot-background {
      fill: none;
    }

    .highcharts-label-box {
      fill: none;
    }

    .highcharts-button-box {
      fill: inherit;
    }


    /* Titles */

    .highcharts-title {
      fill: #333333;
      font-size: 1.5em;
    }

    .highcharts-subtitle {
      fill: #666666;
    }


    /* Axes */

    .highcharts-axis-line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #ccd6eb;
    }

    .highcharts-yaxis .highcharts-axis-line {
      stroke-width: 0;
    }

    .highcharts-axis-title {
      fill: #666666;
    }

    .highcharts-axis-labels {
      fill: #666666;
      cursor: default;
      font-size: 0.9em;
    }

    .highcharts-grid-line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #e6e6e6;
    }

    .highcharts-xaxis-grid .highcharts-grid-line {
      stroke-width: 0;
    }

    .highcharts-tick {
      stroke: #ccd6eb;
    }

    .highcharts-yaxis .highcharts-tick {
      stroke-width: 0;
    }

    .highcharts-minor-grid-line {
      stroke: #f2f2f2;
    }

    .highcharts-crosshair-thin {
      stroke-width: 1px;
      stroke: #cccccc;
    }

    .highcharts-crosshair-category {
      stroke: #ccd6eb;
      stroke-opacity: 0.25;
    }


    /* Credits */

    .highcharts-credits {
      cursor: pointer;
      fill: #999999;
      font-size: 0.7em;
      transition: fill 250ms, font-size 250ms;
    }

    .highcharts-credits:hover {
      fill: black;
      font-size: 1em;
    }


    /* Tooltip */

    .highcharts-tooltip {
      cursor: default;
      pointer-events: none;
      white-space: nowrap;
      transition: stroke 150ms;
    }

    .highcharts-tooltip text {
      fill: #333333;
    }

    .highcharts-tooltip .highcharts-header {
      font-size: 0.85em;
    }

    .highcharts-tooltip-box {
      stroke-width: 1px;
      fill: #f7f7f7;
      fill-opacity: 0.85;
    }

    .highcharts-selection-marker {
      fill: #335cad;
      fill-opacity: 0.25;
    }

    .highcharts-graph {
      fill: none;
      stroke-width: 2px;
      stroke-linecap: round;
      stroke-linejoin: round;
    }

    .highcharts-state-hover .highcharts-graph {
      stroke-width: 3;
    }

    .highcharts-state-hover path {
      transition: stroke-width 50;
      /* quick in */
    }

    .highcharts-state-normal path {
      transition: stroke-width 250ms;
      /* slow out */
    }


    /* Legend hover affects points and series */

    g.highcharts-series,
    .highcharts-point,
    .highcharts-markers,
    .highcharts-data-labels {
      transition: opacity 250ms;
    }

    .highcharts-legend-series-active g.highcharts-series:not(.highcharts-series-hover),
    .highcharts-legend-point-active .highcharts-point:not(.highcharts-point-hover),
    .highcharts-legend-series-active .highcharts-markers:not(.highcharts-series-hover),
    .highcharts-legend-series-active .highcharts-data-labels:not(.highcharts-series-hover) {
      opacity: 0.2;
    }


    /* Series options */


    /* Default colors */

    .highcharts-color-0 {
      fill: #7cb5ec;
      stroke: #7cb5ec;
    }

    .highcharts-color-1 {
      fill: #434348;
      stroke: #434348;
    }

    .highcharts-color-2 {
      fill: #90ed7d;
      stroke: #90ed7d;
    }

    .highcharts-color-3 {
      fill: #f7a35c;
      stroke: #f7a35c;
    }

    .highcharts-color-4 {
      fill: #8085e9;
      stroke: #8085e9;
    }

    .highcharts-color-5 {
      fill: #f15c80;
      stroke: #f15c80;
    }

    .highcharts-color-6 {
      fill: #e4d354;
      stroke: #e4d354;
    }

    .highcharts-color-7 {
      fill: #2b908f;
      stroke: #2b908f;
    }

    .highcharts-color-8 {
      fill: #f45b5b;
      stroke: #f45b5b;
    }

    .highcharts-color-9 {
      fill: #91e8e1;
      stroke: #91e8e1;
    }

    .highcharts-area {
      fill-opacity: 0.75;
      stroke-width: 0;
    }

    .highcharts-markers {
      stroke-width: 1px;
      stroke: #ffffff;
    }

    .highcharts-point {
      stroke-width: 1px;
    }

    .highcharts-dense-data .highcharts-point {
      stroke-width: 0;
    }

    .highcharts-data-label {
      font-size: 0.9em;
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    .highcharts-data-label-box {
      fill: none;
      stroke-width: 0;
    }

    .highcharts-data-label text {
      fill: #333333;
    }

    .highcharts-data-label-connector {
      fill: none;
    }

    .highcharts-halo {
      fill-opacity: 0.25;
      stroke-width: 0;
    }

    .highcharts-point-select {
      fill: #cccccc;
      stroke: #000000;
    }

    .highcharts-column-series rect.highcharts-point {
      stroke: #ffffff;
    }

    .highcharts-column-series .highcharts-point {
      transition: fill-opacity 250ms;
    }

    .highcharts-column-series .highcharts-point-hover {
      fill-opacity: 0.75;
      transition: fill-opacity 50ms;
    }

    .highcharts-pie-series .highcharts-point {
      stroke-linejoin: round;
      stroke: #ffffff;
    }

    .highcharts-pie-series .highcharts-point-hover {
      fill-opacity: 0.75;
      transition: fill-opacity 50ms;
    }

    .highcharts-pie-series .highcharts-point-select {
      fill: inherit;
      stroke: inherit;
    }

    .highcharts-funnel-series .highcharts-point {
      stroke-linejoin: round;
      stroke: #ffffff;
    }

    .highcharts-funnel-series .highcharts-point-hover {
      fill-opacity: 0.75;
      transition: fill-opacity 50ms;
    }

    .highcharts-funnel-series .highcharts-point-select {
      fill: inherit;
      stroke: inherit;
    }

    .highcharts-pyramid-series .highcharts-point {
      stroke-linejoin: round;
      stroke: #ffffff;
    }

    .highcharts-pyramid-series .highcharts-point-hover {
      fill-opacity: 0.75;
      transition: fill-opacity 50ms;
    }

    .highcharts-pyramid-series .highcharts-point-select {
      fill: inherit;
      stroke: inherit;
    }

    .highcharts-solidgauge-series .highcharts-point {
      stroke-width: 0;
    }

    .highcharts-treemap-series .highcharts-point {
      stroke-width: 1px;
      stroke: #e6e6e6;
      transition: stroke 250ms, fill 250ms, fill-opacity 250ms;
    }

    .highcharts-treemap-series .highcharts-point-hover {
      stroke: #999999;
      transition: stroke 25ms, fill 25ms, fill-opacity 25ms;
    }

    .highcharts-treemap-series .highcharts-above-level {
      display: none;
    }

    .highcharts-treemap-series .highcharts-internal-node {
      fill: none;
    }

    .highcharts-treemap-series .highcharts-internal-node-interactive {
      fill-opacity: 0.15;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .highcharts-treemap-series .highcharts-internal-node-interactive:hover {
      fill-opacity: 0.75;
    }


    /* Legend */

    .highcharts-legend-box {
      fill: none;
      stroke-width: 0;
    }

    .highcharts-legend-item text {
      fill: #333333;
      font-weight: bold;
      cursor: pointer;
      stroke-width: 0;
    }

    .highcharts-legend-item:hover text {
      fill: #000000;
    }

    .highcharts-legend-item-hidden * {
      fill: #cccccc !important;
      stroke: #cccccc !important;
      transition: fill 250ms;
    }

    .highcharts-legend-nav-active {
      fill: #003399;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .highcharts-legend-nav-inactive {
      fill: #cccccc;
    }

    .highcharts-legend-title-box {
      fill: none;
      stroke-width: 0;
    }


    /* Loading */

    .highcharts-loading {
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #ffffff;
      opacity: 0.5;
      text-align: center;
      z-index: 10;
      transition: opacity 250ms;
    }

    .highcharts-loading-hidden {
      height: 0 !important;
      opacity: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      transition: opacity 250ms, height 250ms step-end;
    }

    .highcharts-loading-inner {
      font-weight: bold;
      position: relative;
      top: 45%;
    }


    /* Plot bands and polar pane backgrounds */

    .highcharts-plot-band,
    .highcharts-pane {
      fill: #000000;
      fill-opacity: 0.05;
    }

    .highcharts-plot-line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #999999;
      stroke-width: 1px;
    }


    /* Highcharts More */

    .highcharts-boxplot-box {
      fill: #ffffff;
    }

    .highcharts-boxplot-median {
      stroke-width: 2px;
    }

    .highcharts-bubble-series .highcharts-point {
      fill-opacity: 0.5;
    }

    .highcharts-errorbar-series .highcharts-point {
      stroke: #000000;
    }

    .highcharts-gauge-series .highcharts-data-label-box {
      stroke: #cccccc;
      stroke-width: 1px;
    }

    .highcharts-gauge-series .highcharts-dial {
      fill: #000000;
      stroke-width: 0;
    }

    .highcharts-polygon-series .highcharts-graph {
      fill: inherit;
      stroke-width: 0;
    }

    .highcharts-waterfall-series .highcharts-graph {
      stroke: #333333;
      stroke-dasharray: 1, 3;
    }


    /* Highstock */

    .highcharts-navigator-mask-outside {
      fill-opacity: 0;
    }

    .highcharts-navigator-mask-inside {
      fill: #6685c2;
      /* navigator.maskFill option */
      fill-opacity: 0.25;
      cursor: ew-resize;
    }

    .highcharts-navigator-outline {
      stroke: #cccccc;
      fill: none;
    }

    .highcharts-navigator-handle {
      stroke: #cccccc;
      fill: #f2f2f2;
      cursor: ew-resize;
    }

    .highcharts-navigator-series {
      fill: #335cad;
      stroke: #335cad;
    }

    .highcharts-navigator-series .highcharts-graph {
      stroke-width: 1px;
    }

    .highcharts-navigator-series .highcharts-area {
      fill-opacity: 0.05;
    }

    .highcharts-navigator-xaxis .highcharts-axis-line {
      stroke-width: 0;
    }

    .highcharts-navigator-xaxis .highcharts-grid-line {
      stroke-width: 1px;
      stroke: #e6e6e6;
    }

    .highcharts-navigator-xaxis.highcharts-axis-labels {
      fill: #999999;
    }

    .highcharts-navigator-yaxis .highcharts-grid-line {
      stroke-width: 0;
    }

    .highcharts-scrollbar-thumb {
      fill: #cccccc;
      stroke: #cccccc;
      stroke-width: 1px;
    }

    .highcharts-scrollbar-button {
      fill: #e6e6e6;
      stroke: #cccccc;
      stroke-width: 1px;
    }

    .highcharts-scrollbar-arrow {
      fill: #666666;
    }

    .highcharts-scrollbar-rifles {
      stroke: #666666;
      stroke-width: 1px;
    }

    .highcharts-scrollbar-track {
      fill: #f2f2f2;
      stroke: #f2f2f2;
      stroke-width: 1px;
    }

    .highcharts-button {
      fill: #f7f7f7;
      stroke: #cccccc;
      cursor: default;
      stroke-width: 1px;
      transition: fill 250ms;
    }

    .highcharts-button text {
      fill: #333333;
    }

    .highcharts-button-hover {
      transition: fill 0ms;
      fill: #e6e6e6;
      stroke: #333333;
    }

    .highcharts-button-pressed {
      font-weight: bold;
      fill: #e6ebf5;
      stroke: #335cad;
    }

    .highcharts-button-disabled text {
      fill: #cccccc;
    }

    .highcharts-range-selector-buttons .highcharts-button {
      stroke-width: 0;
    }

    .highcharts-range-label rect {
      fill: none;
    }

    .highcharts-range-label text {
      fill: #666666;
    }

    .highcharts-range-input rect {
      fill: none;
    }

    .highcharts-range-input text {
      fill: #333333;
    }

    input.highcharts-range-selector {
      position: absolute;
      border: 0;
      width: 1px;
      /* Chrome needs a pixel to see it */
      height: 1px;
      padding: 0;
      text-align: center;
      left: -9em;
      /* #4798 */
    }

    .highcharts-crosshair-label text {
      fill: #ffffff;
      font-size: 1.1em;
    }

    .highcharts-crosshair-label .highcharts-label-box {
      fill: inherit;
    }

    .highcharts-candlestick-series .highcharts-point {
      stroke: #000000;
      stroke-width: 1px;
    }

    .highcharts-candlestick-series .highcharts-point-up {
      fill: #ffffff;
    }

    .highcharts-ohlc-series .highcharts-point-hover {
      stroke-width: 3px;
    }

    .highcharts-flags-series .highcharts-point {
      stroke: #999999;
      fill: #ffffff;
    }

    .highcharts-flags-series .highcharts-point-hover {
      stroke: #000000;
      fill: #ccd6eb;
    }

    .highcharts-flags-series .highcharts-point text {
      fill: #000000;
      font-size: 0.9em;
      font-weight: bold;
    }


    /* Highmaps */

    .highcharts-map-series .highcharts-point {
      transition: fill 500ms, fill-opacity 500ms, stroke-width 250ms;
      stroke: #cccccc;
    }

    .highcharts-map-series .highcharts-point-hover {
      transition: fill 0ms, fill-opacity 0ms;
      fill-opacity: 0.5;
      stroke-width: 2px;
    }

    .highcharts-mapline-series .highcharts-point {
      fill: none;
    }

    .highcharts-heatmap-series .highcharts-point {
      stroke-width: 0;
    }

    .highcharts-map-navigation {
      font-size: 1.3em;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .highcharts-coloraxis {
      stroke-width: 0;
    }

    .highcharts-coloraxis-marker {
      fill: #999999;
    }

    .highcharts-null-point {
      fill: #f7f7f7;
    }


    /* 3d charts */

    .highcharts-3d-frame {
      fill: transparent;
    }


    /* Exporting module */

    .highcharts-contextbutton {
      fill: #ffffff;
      /* needed to capture hover */
      stroke: none;
      stroke-linecap: round;
    }

    .highcharts-contextbutton:hover {
      fill: #e6e6e6;
      stroke: #e6e6e6;
    }

    .highcharts-button-symbol {
      stroke: #666666;
      stroke-width: 3px;
    }

    .highcharts-menu {
      border: 1px solid #999999;
      background: #ffffff;
      padding: 5px 0;
      box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px #888;
    }

    .highcharts-menu-item {
      padding: 0.5em 1em;
      background: none;
      color: #333333;
      cursor: pointer;
      transition: background 250ms, color 250ms;
    }

    .highcharts-menu-item:hover {
      background: #335cad;
      color: #ffffff;
    }


    /* Drilldown module */

    .highcharts-drilldown-point {
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .highcharts-drilldown-data-label text,
    .highcharts-drilldown-axis-label {
      cursor: pointer;
      fill: #003399;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-decoration: underline;
    }


    /* No-data module */

    .highcharts-no-data text {
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 12px;
      fill: #666666;
    }

    .chart-container {
      background: transparent;
    }

    .highcharts-background {
      fill: transparent;
    }

    .highcharts-plot-background {
      background-color: transparent;
    }

    .highcharts-pie-series .customSeries1 {
      border-radius: 20px;
      fill: #007272;
    }

    .highcharts-pie-series .customSeries2 {
      fill: #e76a0b;
      border-radius: 20px;
    }

    .highcharts-tooltip-box {
      stroke-width: 0;
    }

    .highcharts-plot-band {
      fill: white;
      fill-opacity: 1;
      stroke-width: 1px;
      stroke: lightgray;
    }

    .highcharts-minor-grid-line,
    .highcharts-grid-line {
      stroke-width: 0;
    }

    .highcharts-pane {
      fill: white
    }

    .highcharts-plot-band-label {
      font-size: 12px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    .container {
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 400px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/js/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/js/highcharts-more.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div id="gauge1" class="gauge"></div>
</div>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/remisture/Lhn69g8y/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`yAxis.tickAmount`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.max/yAxis.tickAmount) value seems to be overridden and assumed to be 5 when you set it to `0` in your code, which then rounds your max upwards as described in [`yAxis.max`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.max).

I had success in your example by either removing it entirely or setting it like this ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lhn69g8y/2/)):

```
yAxis: {
      tickAmount: undefined
      // ...
}
```

Comment: Life saver. 100% my problem